# drag div to the boundries of the window without auto scroll appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

when I drag my div 'header' to the bottom of the page the window begins to scroll and continues dragging. I want it to stop when it reaches the bottom of the window and not to scroll, I thought the code below would achieve this, but evidently it doesn't. any ideas how this can be done? Thanks.

```
$("#header").draggable({containment: 'window',scroll: false });
```

Comment: It works in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJ8ZZ/). What version of jQuery UI are you using? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors, version 1.10.1. I see it worked in the jsfiddle. I'll have to think what else it could be. I assumed it was something wrong with the code but it must be something else. Thanks

Comment: OK, I figured it out, it had another div wrapped in it, and that was not set to scroll false. Thanks for confirming the code was sound